# Code 128 (dhl) barcode and something missing in bars

Tags: barcode, zpl, bc, code128, dhl

Currently I'm creating dhl label using zpl command. I'm new to zpl commands.

I have used BC - zpl command for code 128 barcode. This is my code:

```
^BCN,,N,N^FD>:2LDE44536+99000900153004^FS
```

My problem: Above zpl code create barcodes, but when I check this barcode 
http://barcode.tec-it.com/
value : 2LDE44536+99000900153004

my barcode bars look different.

Please guide me right format use here for get right barcode.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you scanned both codes to compare data? Check the manual to be sure, but the `>:` is specifying subset B (Normal Alpha Numeric). Your `+` symbol may be getting dropped.

[ZPL Manual](http://www.zebra.com/id/zebra/na/en/documentlibrary/manuals/en/zpl_ii_programming2.File.tmp/45541L-002_RA.pdf)